# Clearing a Textinput using a TouchableOpacity without dismissing the keyboard?

Tags: react-native, textinput, expo, touchableopacity

i want to build a super simple chat. 
To do that a got an TextInput and a TouchableOpacity to send the message and 
clear the Textinput.

Problem: When i send the message the Textinput is cleared BUT when start writing again the old text is copied in the Textinput again (+ the new character). 
However if the keyboard is dismissed after sending and clearing everything works 
perfectly fine.

Is there any way to clear the TextInput completly with a TouchableOpacity?

Below is the code and a few tries by myself but none of them worked.
Thanks in advance,

Maffinius

```js
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TextInput
      placeholder="Schreibe eine Nachricht"
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newMsg : text})}
      style={{width: 300}}
      ref={'ref1'}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this.sendMessage}
      >
      <Text> --> </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

```js
sendMessage = () => {
  this.state.MsgData.push({msg: this.state.newMsg, id: this.props.global.userId, timestamp: 8888});
  this.refs['ref1'].clear();
  this.setState({newMsg: ""});
  //this.refs['ref1'].setNativeProps({text: ''})
  //Keyboard.dismiss();

}
```

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultValue` prop for setting the value of the state (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#defaultvalue)

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Schreibe eine Nachricht"
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({newMsg : text})}
  style={{width: 300}}
  ref={(input) => this.ref1 = input}
  defaultValue={this.state.newMsg}
/>
```

See this example for full implementation: https://snack.expo.io/SkuH8hKPb

Comment: shouldn't it just be value?

Comment: First of all thx for the fast response:
The code example is almost working BUT you have to add a whitespace after the message text (otherwise the last word or character is still copied in the textinput when i start writing again). Is there any way to fix this? (adding a whitespace manually doesnt work aparantly).